# Wix - Msi :How to check if a particular row exists in a msi Data table or not

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I want to check if a particular row exists in Data table or not.

E.g., I want to check if Property Table Exists in msi data table or not. If it exists then I want to check if "Property" column and "Value" column exists or not. If both exists then I want to check if Property "ARPNOMODIFY" exists or not.

```
                if (database.Tables.Contains("Property"))
                {
                    if (database.Tables["Property"].Columns.Contains("Property"))
                    {
                        // here I want to checked if "ARPNOMODIFY" or any other property exists or not. If it exists then I want its value.
                    }
                }
```

I have one data table having structure as( "TableName","ColumnNAme1","ColumnName2","Value at ColumnName1"). So for above record the row is like ("Property","Property","Value","ARPNOMODIFY") and I want to return Value 1 as ARPNOMODIFY exists and its value is 1.

Now consider another row as ("Property","Propery","Value","ICFAGREE"). Now if ICFAGREE property doesn't exists in Property table then I want to return null string.
Thanks in advance.

Also Consider another row ("AdminExecuteSequence","Action","Condition","SetSpecifiedDir"). Now in this example AdminExecuteSequence table has Action and Condition columns. One of value under Action columns is "SetSpecifiedDir" so its corresponding value under "Condition" column is "ORCADIR".So I want to return "ORCADIR" this string, If "SetSpecifiedDir" value exists in AdminExecuteSequence table or else I would return null.

Comment: Since certain properties are required in MSIs, you shouldn't have a database that doesn't contain the `Property` table.

Comment: yeah. Property table was just for an example. But some Property table may contain ARPNOMODIFY property and some may not. Also some msis contain RemoveFile table and some msis don't. SO want to check if perticular table exists or not and if exista then perticular row exists or not. I am getting this specific information from datatable (strusture is["TableName","ColumnName1","ColumnName2","Value in ColumnNAme1"] )and I want to return value at columnName2. In short I want to make join of DataTable with msi Datatable.

Comment: Are you using DTF (Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller)?  You seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTF has rich classes to help you do these kinds of tests.

[Also see: MSI Tip: Authoring an ICE using C# / DTF](http://blog.iswix.com/2009/02/msi-tip-authoring-ice-using-c-dtf.html)

```
   using System;
    using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Tester : IDisposable
        {
            Database _database;

            public Tester(string databasePath)
            {
                _database = new Database(databasePath, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _database.Dispose();
            }

            public bool HasTable(string tableName)
            {
                return _database.Tables.Contains(tableName);
            }

            public bool HasColumn(string tableName, string columnName)
            {
                bool columnExists = false;
                if (HasTable(tableName))
                {
                    columnExists = _database.Tables[tableName].Columns.Contains(columnName);
                }
                return columnExists;
            }


            public bool QueryReturnsData(string sqlStatement, params object[] args)
            {
                return QueryReturnsData(string.Format(sqlStatement, args));
            }

            public bool QueryReturnsData(string sqlStatement)
            {
                bool containsData = false;
                using (View view = _database.OpenView(sqlStatement))
                {
                    view.Execute();
                    using (Record rec = view.Fetch())
                    {
                        if(rec != null )
                        {
                            containsData = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return containsData;

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is API for retrieving a property value: [MsiGetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: To query if any table exists you can use [MsiDatabaseGetPrimaryKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you a C# developer and if so, are you aware of DTF?